# Loopback recording on Windows using GStreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer, loopback, directsound, wasapi

How can I record system sounds and sounds played by other apps? I tried `directsoundsrc` and `wasapisrc` with no luck. DirectSound seems to be unable to capture from Speakers (devices listed by `DirectSoundEnumerate`).

`DirectSoundCaptureEnumerate` returns me my Mic only, no output devices listed.

Comment: any warning/error from gstreamer upon using directsoundsrc? I found [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Capture-audio-using-directsoundsrc-windows-td4671262.html) post.. what version of gstreamer?

Comment: `directsoundsrc` will capture from mic by default. It will not capture, if I will put GUID of output device instead.